# Connecting external mic to the Teensy

Tags: teensy

I have a Teensy 3.2 and the [Teensy audio board](https://www.pjrc.com/store/teensy3_audio.html).

I was going to connect lavalier microphone to its audio jack but learned that it's only for output.
There are line-in pins though (see "Back Side" scheme). And MIC+GND pins, but these are for, ehm, radio parts microphones, I guess?

Being a complete novice I have no idea how to connect microphone jack (or audio connector) to line-in pins and whether I would need an amplifier between microphone and pins. If so then probably I just can't do it.

I would be grateful for detailed instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier than I thought! I soldered audio jack to MIC+GND, inserted microphone in and it works!
And pretty well :-)
Cheap random lavalier model: Panasonic RP-VC201. I guess any consumer model will do.